# ASP.NET- Prompt confirmation only if needed

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a button. And I have a Session["actionMode"]. Here what I do in my buttonClick event:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    if ((int)Session["actionMode"]==1)
    {
      //Do something
    }
    else if ((int)Session["actionMode"]==3)
    {
       //After confirmation delete a record
    }

}
```

As you can see if value of Session["actionMode"] equals 3  a record is deleted. But before deletion I want to prompt the user to confirm the action. So if value of Session["actionMode"] does not equal 3 I don't need any confirmation because it does not do anything that can't be undone. Is there a way I can achieve this? Javascript maybe?

Comment: Is it possible to use the `actionMode` mode value on button rendering time? Or you need to check it only when button clicked?

Comment: actionMode is a variable kept in Session object. So I'm guessing it's available on button rendering. I need to check it when button is clicked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code block...

```
{ 
    //After confirmation delete a record 
}
```

You are executing server side code, and in need for user interaction.

Whatever you do (client or server) you have to split this. A server side alternative.

```
{ 
    // Display a confirmation including server side controls.
}

protected void YesDeleteTheDamnRecord_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Delete it now.
}
```

And here is one solution with client side interaction.

> - Check the value of "actionMode" way before displaying Button1.
> - If it's equal to "3" attach a client side event handler to    Button1.OnClientClick.
> - Display a confirmation (window.confirm maybe)
> - If user clicks "Yes" execute server side code and delete the record.

Comment: Thank you Yigit Yenr. Chozumun muhteshem!!. :)

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to use following approach for deletion.....

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
      if ((int)Session["actionMode"]==1)
     {
       //Do something
     }
     else if ((int)Session["actionMode"]==3)
     {
        //Call Javascript Function which will call Ajax
     }
  }
```

**Javascript:**

```
function callAjax()
{
   if(confirm(do you want to delete data?))
   {
     call Ajax Page
   }
   else
   {
     return;
   }
}
```

**Ajax Page:**

```
  PageLoad
  {
    Get Session["actionMode"] Value
    Do your Delete here...
  }
```